# Laravel 5 "Custom" Form Methods

Tags: forms, laravel, laravel-5

Trying to get this form to send using a PATCH request

```
<form method="POST" action="...">
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH">
```

but not having any luck with my route method set to PATCH, this does work however if I manually change the form method. Does this no longer work in L5?

--

Ugh, nevermind it works fine. Messed up my routing, was pointing my form to /users instead of /users/[id]

Comment: It still works in L5. Are you getting a `MethodNotAllowed` exception or something else? http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#method-spoofing Did you forget the CSRF token, i.e. `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">`?

Comment: Yep you're right it works fine. Messed up where I was posting the form to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patch requests work fine as long as you don't screw up your route names :)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting enough another option is to use the helper function `method_field()` which will create the `_method` field for you automatically. It looks nice and clean and is easier and faster to type (IMO).

An example would be like this:

```
<form action="{{route('posts.update', $post->id)}}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('PUT') }}
    <input type="text">
</form>
```

As you can see there is also another helper called `csrf_field()` which also creates the necessary csrf hidden field.

The `method_field()` requires one parameter, which would be a string indicating the value of your "custom method". So this is generally `PUT`, `PATCH`, or `DELETE`. Also make sure that you still set your form to the `POST` method in the form html tag. All of these custom methods are really just `POST` methods in disguise, so you need to set it as such in the form tag.

So when blade renders this file, your resulting page source would look like this:

```
<form action="http://localhost:8000/posts/1" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="Fe16wD6lkMmWDYyoUkGaYPzzcf7wHm58eKs3P6YU">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
    <input type="text>
</form>
```

It is another way to achieve the same result. But for me, I prefer my forms being easy to read like this:

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
{{ method_field('PUT') }}
```

I just wanted to throw this out there for newcomers since it is easier to handle and isn't documented very well.